# Hardware essentials for workstation using Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard

My windows workstation is pretty well setup.  I dislike laptop keyboards because everybody has their own setup of the keys, and since I am a touch typist, I use a standard QWERTY 101 keyboard.

I am just starting Mac development.

What is a good keyboard to get for my shiny new Macbook Pro?

What should I look for in a good monitor for the Macbook Pro?

Is there a KVM switch that I can use to flip between the Macbook Pro and my Windows workstation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what hardware to buy.

Answer (score 2):

I would get a standard US Layout Apple Wired Keyboard, a Dell 27" ultra sharp monitor... They use the same panels as the Apple plant for a fraction of the price.
as for a KVM switch, no experience with that, you can however install windows on your mac using bootcamp (recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Our setup for developing with a MacBook Pro consists of:

- Griffin Elevator (http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/elevator)
- Apple Keyboard with Numeric Pad (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/A)
- A Dell monitor with Display Port such as the UltraSharp U2211H (http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/Displays/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-9271)
- A Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable from Monoprice (http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6006&seq=1&format=2)
- Any mouse you feel comfortable with

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard: I use the Apple keyboard with numeric pad (wired).  I have tried other keyboards, but they tend not to work very well when I run Windows under BootCamp.  (It sounds like you have a separate Windows machine, though, so this might not be a problem for you.)  I have tried several keyboards and have found that only the Apple keyboards work really well with the Mac.  The primary reason for this is the quick key shortcuts

Monitor: I use a Dell Monitor 24" my with Mac.  It has multiple inputs including a DisplayPort, which will work well with your MacBook Pro.  You just need the displayport adapter from MonoPrice (www.monoprice.com).

As an alternative, you mention the use of a KVM.  In my experience, cheap KVMs are cheap and do not work well.  I have used KVMs from several manufacturers.  The one I have found to be the best is one from Avocent (www.avocent.com).  They have KVMs that are called SwitchView Desktop KVMs and they work very well.  They have ones that work with DVI ports.  You can get a DVI adapter for your MacBook Pro.

If you are looking for a keyboard/mouse combo, I would recommend the Logitech products.  I recommend the ones that are NOT Bluetooth.  They can be plugged into the Avocent KVM and work perfectly.

Hope this helps!